# cannot do .hide on a dialog ERROR: Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object

Tags: android, android-studio, dialog

I'm trying to dismiss my costume alert dialog but it errors me -

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.Dialog.dismiss()'
>   on a null object reference

but the object isn't null i initialize it before hand. and i don't understand why it is null,

but then when i do - mainDialog.hide()

it errors me out that I'm trying to do hide on a null reference.

I don't really know why this is happening.

this is my activity

```
package apps.radwin.wintouch;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;

import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

import apps.radwin.wintouch.devicePackage.wifiWrapper;
import apps.radwin.wintouch.screenManagers.aligmentManager;

public class Scanning_Barcode_Activity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, View.OnClickListener {

    //declare locals
    ImageView backgroundImage;
    Button scanButton, nextButton;
    TextView scanBarcodeText, loaderScreenMainText;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    SharedPreferences boxSharedPref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Dialog mainDialog;

    aligmentManager aligmentManagerClass =  new aligmentManager();
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.scanning_barcode_layout);

        //brings up the toolbar to view
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //inserts the Fab Button
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        //navigation view handler
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //START OF IMPLEMENTATION
        //CASTING and POINTING TO DISPLAY
        backgroundImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.scanningBarcodeScreen_imageView_bacgkroundImage);
        scanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scanningBarcodeScreen_button_scanButton);
        nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scanningBarcodeScreen_button_nextButton);
        scanBarcodeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scanningBarcodeScreen_textView_scanHeadline);

        //prepers the shared prefrence
        boxSharedPref = getSharedPreferences("ULCSharePrefrenceTable", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = boxSharedPref.edit();


        //add listeners
        scanButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        //assining an image
        backgroundImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.barcodeactivitybg);

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();

        //notify's the aligment manager that the screen has entered
        aligmentManagerClass.barcodeScreenInitilized(getApplicationContext());

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.scanning__barcode_, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_aligment) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Scanning_Barcode_ Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://apps.radwin.wintouch/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Scanning_Barcode_ Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://apps.radwin.wintouch/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
        client.disconnect();
    }


    //listener for buttons
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

//
//        loadToastModule loadToastMD = new loadToastModule();
//        LoadToast lt = loadToastMD.getWidget(this, "Loading");

        switch (v.getId()) {

            //scan button was pressed
            case R.id.scanningBarcodeScreen_button_scanButton:

                aligmentManagerClass.pressedScanBarcodeButton(); //notify aligment manager scan was pressed

                new IntentIntegrator(this).initiateScan(); // opens up Scan intent > ZXING

                break;

            //next button was pressed
            case R.id.scanningBarcodeScreen_button_nextButton:

                //showLoadingScreen();
                aligmentManagerClass.pressedNextButtonFromBarcodeScreen();

                break;


        }

    }

    public void showLoadingScreen() {

    }

    Callable  wifiStateCallback = new Callable() {

        @Override
        public Object call() throws Exception {

            return null;
        }
    };


    //Interface for the callback function - Defyining the interface
    public interface isWifiOnCallableInterface {

        void isWifiOnCallable(boolean result);
    }

    //the actual callback that will be called once the call will come back
    isWifiOnCallableInterface callbackFunctionForisWifiOn  = new isWifiOnCallableInterface() {

        @Override
        public void isWifiOnCallable(boolean result) {

            Log.d ("myLogs", "One?");

            if (result == true) { //wifi is ON

            }else { //wifi is OFF

                try {
                    mainDialog.hide(); //THIS IS MY PROBLEM IN HERE , THIS IS MY PROBLEM IN HERE
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

//                AlertDialog offdialog = getAlertDialogForWifiOff(); //shows to user alert dialog for wifi is off
//                offdialog.show(); // show it

            }
        }
    };


    public AlertDialog getAlertDialogForWifiOff () {

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                Scanning_Barcode_Activity.this);


        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Wifi Problem");// set title


        alertDialogBuilder // set dialog message
                .setMessage("Yopur wifi is OFF please click Turn On to turn it back on")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Turn ON",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) { //on button clicked

                        wifiWrapper WifiWrapper = new wifiWrapper();
                        WifiWrapper.toggleWiFi(Scanning_Barcode_Activity.this, true); // turns wifi ON

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Exit APP",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) { // exit app button clicked
//                        dialog.cancel(); - cancels the dialog
                        Scanning_Barcode_Activity.this.finish(); // exits app
                    }
                });

        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        return alertDialog;

    }


    //results when activity enters a callback sent out to another activity
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

        IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent); //retrieve scan result

        aligmentManagerClass.gotScanFromBarcode();

        if (scanningResult != null) {

            String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents(); //we have a result
            String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();

            try { //sets the text to scan content

                Log.d("myLogs", "length is: " + scanContent.length()); //scan sucssesful
                scanBarcodeText.setText(scanContent);

                editor.putString("boxID", scanContent); //saves the data as antenaNamein shared prefrences
                editor.commit();

                if (checkIfIdMatched(scanContent) == true) { //checkks if id is maching the one in the workorder

                    aligmentManagerClass.scanFromBarcodeApproved(); //ID MACHED

                    wifiWrapper myWifiWrapper = new wifiWrapper(); //- INIZILIZING WIFI
                    myWifiWrapper.checkWifiState(this, callbackFunctionForisWifiOn);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //do something in case scan fails
                aligmentManagerClass.scanFromBarcodeFailed(); //ID MACHED

            }

            mainDialog = getCostumeDialog ();
            mainDialog.show(); //initlizes the costume dialog


        } else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }



    //gets a costume dialog to use
    private Dialog getCostumeDialog() {

        Dialog loadingDialog = new Dialog(this);
        //loadingDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        loadingDialog.setContentView(R.layout.aligment_manager_loader_layout);
        //dialog.setTitle("Loading");
        //sets the dialog Cancelable
        loadingDialog.setCancelable(true);

        //set up text
        //loaderScreenMainText.setText("Loading Wifi");

        //progressBar = (ProgressBar) dialog.findViewById(R.id.barcodeScanning_spinkit);
        //DoubleBounce doubleBounce = new DoubleBounce();
        //progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(doubleBounce);
        //loadingProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);

        //now that the dialog is set up, it's time to show it

        return loadingDialog;

    }

    //checkks if id is maching the one in the workorder
    private boolean checkIfIdMatched(String unitId) {
        boolean isMached = true;
        //for now just simulates a working order that returns true
        return isMached;
    }


}
```

can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have his error because your variable `mainDialog` is `null` when you call the `hide` method.

I don't know the logic of your code, but the easiest way to get rid of this error is to check if the `mainDialog` variable has been initialized :

```
if (mainDialog != null) {
    mainDialog.hide();
}
```

Comment: Dialog loadingDialog = new Dialog(Scanning_Barcode_Activity.this);  can you try this as @sonic told you its null for sure

Comment: tried to change from Dialog loadingDialog = new Dialog(this);, to what's suggested here > Dialog loadingDialog = new Dialog(Scanning_Barcode_Activity.this);. it didn't changed anything but it is initlized.. so really don't understand this.. + why do people do -1 to my question ?

Comment: Reading your code, i see that you set your wifi callback *before* creating the dialog. So your dialog is *not* initialized when the code of your callback is called. Just add the test `mainDialog != null` before you call hide and you will be fine.

Comment: Thnx @sonic you really helped me out !!! (btw for next time do you know why people give me - points for this question ?)

Answer (score 0):

```
 mainDialog = getCostumeDialog ();
```

call this on create since mainDialog is global , in this manner it will be initialized then button click will happen and onactivityResultback will get called

Comment: then the loadingDialog will never be used, i'm using the function getCostumeDialog, to return a dialog to mainDialog that will be used on that function.

Comment: mainDialog = getCostumeDialog (); is on activityResultBack  and you seems to hiding it before that that is null

Comment: Thnx for helping ! changed the mainDialog = getCostumDialot() to onCreate... still the same problem @Haroon